# matplotlib python , how to set diffrent block with diffrent color and name

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = {'Mon':(0,0.5), 'Tue': (0.7,1), 'Wen': (0.1,0.3), 'Th': (0.3,0.4)
       ,'Fri':(0.1,0.2),'Sat':(0.1,0.4),'Sun':(0,0)
       }
width = 0.5 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, values in enumerate(data.values()):
    ymin, ymax = values
    ax.axvspan(xmin=i-width/2, xmax=i+width/2, ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax)

ax.grid(True)

#add ticks
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,len(data)))
ax.set_xticklabels(data.keys())
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,37))
time_list = [
       '6:00','6:30','7:00','7:30',
       '8:00','8:30','9:00','9:30',
       '10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30',
       '12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30',
       '14:00','14:30','15:00','15:30',
       '16:00','16:30','17:00','17:30',
       '18:00','18:30','19:00','19:30',
       '20:00','20:30','21:00','21:30',
       '22:00','22:30','23:00','23:30',
       '24:00',
       ]
ax.set_yticklabels(x for x in time_list)
plt.show()
```

[image: Current Output img]

Hi ! Can anyone tell me how do I set different blocks with different color and name in pyplot?

For example:  Block 1 : Mon 6:00-15:00 (color red , name: Accounting 1)   , Block 2: Tue 18:30-24:00( color yellow ,name: Spanish 2)

I have tried several ways by using "plt.bar" function and many others from the documentation but they didn't work and I may have done something wrong, can anyone help?

Above is the code and I included the current output img as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a color parameter to `ax.axvspan()` and use `ax.text()` to set arbitrary labels. I'll only show that part of your code where I made changes.

*Edit:* The position coordinates that `ax.text()` takes are data coordinates by default. So we can use the same value for the x-coordinate that we use to draw the rectangle. For the y-coordinate, we have to transform the value from the [0, 1] interval to the data grid. Since we have (24 - 6) * 2 = 36 gridlines, that is the transformation factor. Give or take some offset. To keep the labels within the grid, we can make a case distinction and plot the label beneath the rectangle if there is no space above it.

```py
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'gray', 'gray', 'gray', 'gray', 'gray']
labels = ['Accounting 1', 'Spanish 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4', 'Label 5', 'Label 6', '']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[15, 12])

for i, values in enumerate(data.values()):
    ymin, ymax = values
    ax.axvspan(xmin=i-width/2, xmax=i+width/2, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, 
               color=colors[i])
    if ymax < 35/36:
        label_y = 36 * ymax + 0.25
    else:
        label_y = 36 * ymin - 1
    ax.text(i-width/2, label_y, labels[i], fontsize=16)
```

[image: colors and labels demonstration]

Comment: One more question, so for the ax.text fucntion , is there anyway to set the position autommally base on the "data = {'Mon':(0,0.5), ..." that I made earller ?

Comment: since the range for y interceprt is 0.0 to 1.0 but the text fucnton can take negative argument

Comment: @chris chen Sure, I added a way to do this to the answer.